# How to delete all shopping cart items of all customers in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I want to delete all shopping cart items (products added to cart) of all customers in Magento.

How can I do that?

**In detail**:-

Suppose, I have total 10 registered customers in my shop. They might have items (products) added to cart. I want to clear all items added to cart for all the 10 registered customers.

Comment: What you mean all shopping cart items?

Comment: I want to help you but there's at least 5 different ways to interpret this question.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first guess would be something like,

```
$items = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_item_collection');

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $item->delete();
}
```

The cart items are stored as part of a 'quote'. Looping through them all like this might be slow, doing it in SQL is quicker but not as safe.

```
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`;
```

Comment: This query seems more safe: DELETE FROM `sales_flat_quote` WHERE is_active = 1;

Comment: `DELETE FROM sales_flat_quote` will also cause a cascade delete which removes the addresses, payments and shipping options that customers may have partially filled out.  To be more correct it should be `DELETE FROM sales_flat_quote_item INNER JOIN sales_flat_quote ON quote_id = entity_id WHERE is_active = 1`

Answer (score 2):

I know, it's not related directly your question but might be help.

Inchoo has published an article a few days ago which is putting "Cart Empty" link on cart page.

[There’s no “EMPTY CART” on Magento’s cart page](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/theres-no-empty-cart-on-magentos-cart-page/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20Inchoo%20%28Magento,%20Wordpress,%20Online%20Marketing,%20iPhone%20development%20@%20Inchoo%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader)

Comment: I was reluctant to suggest an SQL answer because it fails to call events that might be required somewhere else. Inchoo's method uses `removeItem` which has such an event, that is why it's the better way.

Comment: Inchoo's module is fit for customers where individual customers can empty their cart. However, I want to delete all customers' cart items at a time. Hence, I thought to go with SQL.